# Groupby count for every hour with count value 0 also

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have a list of person and I want count of person register every hour. I have used below `GroupBy` clause and I got the correct result.

```
var persons = lstPerson.GroupBy(x =>(x.CreatedOn.Hour))
                       .Select(grp => new { total = grp.Count(), key = grp.Key })
                       .OrderBy(x => x.key)
                       .ToList();
```

But I want for every hour. It only shows the value in which count is there. If for 1st hour no person is registered then it doesn't show 0 count in list.

So for example there are person registered only for 13, 14,15 hours(means at 13:00,14:00 and 15:00 hours) then it shows the count for it but not for other hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of options:

Firstly, and with least change to your code, you can just "add one" to each group and then "subtract one" from each count:

```
var persons = lstPerson
    .Select(x => (x.CreatedOn.Hour))  // Get the hours from the people
    .Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 24))  // Add an extra copy of each hour
    .GroupBy(h => h)                      // ↓ subtract the extra hours
    .Select(grp => new { total = grp.Count() - 1, key = grp.Key })
    .OrderBy(x => x.key)
    .ToList();
```

Secondly, more tidy but involves replacing all of your code, you can join the list of people onto the list of hours:

```
var persons = Enumerable.Range(0, 24)
    .GroupJoin(
        lstPerson,
        h => h,                  // Correlate the hours in the range
        p => p.CreatedOn.Hour,   // with the hours from each person
        (h, ps) => new { total = ps.Count(), key = h))
    .ToList();    // ↑ This selects one element for each hour in the range
```

Comment: Can you please let me know which one is better as performance wise? Thank you.

Comment: I'd imagine they're pretty similar. If you're worried about performance, run them both and see which is quicker.